# readfile vulnerability how to avoid

Tags: php, security, curl, readfile

I heard that the function readfile is vulnerable as a php function, so I disabled it, and I have a script to download files, which uses this function:

```
$url = strip_tags($_GET['path']);

$fileName = strip_tags($_GET['file']);

header ("Content-type: octet/stream");
header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName.";");
header ("Content-Length: ".filesize($url.$fileName));
readfile($url.$fileName);
exit;
```

If it is vulnerable, is there a way to avoid it or replace it with another function, I tried cURL, but the download failed, I got from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6409531/revisions)

Using cURL:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/localfile.tmp', 'w+');//This is the file where we save the    information
$ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$url));//Here is the file we are downloading, replace spaces with %20
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // write curl response to file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch); // get curl response
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: readfile is only vulnerable if you fail to follow the simplest of best practises, e.g. sanitising user input.

Comment: I updated my question, added both params url and fileName

Answer (score 1):

readfile isn't vulnerable per se. A possible attack vector is only given, when you pass un-sanitized data as parameter to it.

I mean `$url`. Your example doesn't show where URL comes from.

Let's use the worst case and assume $url comes from $_POST, e.g.

`$url = $_POST['url'];` and combine it with a nice Path Traversal attack (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal).

You could limit the file access to the current dir (`__DIR__`).
Or use `realpath()` and exclude/restrict what readfile can do.

Referencing: [How to avoid path traversal attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/File_System#Path_traversal)

---

Ok, i've tested you cURL example. It works!

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/news/rss';

set_time_limit(0);
$fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/localfile.tmp', 'w+');//This is the file where we save the    information
$ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$url));//Here is the file we are downloading, replace spaces with %20
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // write curl response to file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch); // get curl response
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

This downloads the content of the news/rss feed URL and saves it to `localfile.tmp`.

Comment: $url is coming from §_GET, 
I updated my question, added both params url and fileName, 
could you give an example of usinf __DIR__ and realpath()?

Comment: The basic example is to restrict access to the current dir, e.g. `readfile(__DIR__.'/'.$file)`. (This is the case, when you simply want to send a file from your own server. You can then drop the URL part.)

Comment: But your example looks like you want to use readfile() on a URL, right? That means you have to enable `allow_url_fopen` in `php.ini` to fetch the data. Which is also a big security risk, because it allows to fetch arbitrary data, if you don't use a whitelist for the URLs. This is called remote file inclusion attack. In other words: when you really want to retrieve remote content, then cURL is only way to do it - probably in combination with a whitelist (to restrict the remote access).

Comment: allow_url_fopen is enabled, I tried cURL with this example, updated my question above, but it does NOT download a file

Comment: Yes, it's better to use cURL, it's safer

Comment: This is the [link](http://www.alfirdaous.com/Sawtiyat/Quoran/TilawatSheikhs/AhmadAlObaid/Murattal-1/Listen-1.html) to test, click on download using cURL, it will not open the download dialog, however, using readfile will do

Comment: So this is the way I posted it:

    `$url = strip_tags($_GET['path']);
     $fileName = strip_tags($_GET['file']);
    set_time_limit(0);
    $fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/localfile.tmp', 'w+');
    $ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$url.$fileName));//Here is the file we are downloading, replace spaces with %20
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // write curl response to file
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
   curl_exec($ch); // get curl response
   curl_close($ch);
   fclose($fp);`